# Collect with rational powers

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, sorting

I need a function, which will collect terms next to the same rational power of a given variable. For the input

```
RCollect[3xy^(3/2)+2/y+zx/y-y/x+2*x^z y^(3/2),y]
```

the desired output is

```
(2+zx)y^(-1)-y/x+(3x+2x^z)y^(3/2).
```

I'm aware that output is ambiguous when powers of the RCollect variables are unspecified `RCollect[2 x^k1+3 x^k2]`. In such a case, the function should collect terms next to `x^k1` and `x^k2` separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first advise that the expressions like `xz` Mathematica understands as a new variable, rather than a product. To define a product, you should instead write either `x z` (with white space) or `x*z`.

There is no need for a special function for your task. `Collect` makes the job like follows:
Here is your expression:

```
expr = 3 x y^(3/2) + 2/y + z x/y - y/x + 2*x^z y^(3/2);
```

Let us first prepare a list for `Collect`:

```
lst = (Map[Exponent[#, y] &, List @@ expr] // DeleteDuplicates) /. 
  x_ -> y^x

(*  {1/y, y, y^(3/2)} *)
```

Now:

```
Collect[expr, lst]

(*  -(y/x) + (3 x + 2 x^z) y^(3/2) + (2 + x z)/y  *)
```

Have fun!